# ClientAbortException java.io.IOException: Broken pipe issue with Graph QL client and Java backend application

Tags: java, graphql, httpclient, connection-pooling

I am facing ClientAbortException java.io.IOException: Broken pipe error with Java Backend service. I am using Graph QL client using Python.

We have message queue which will communicate with client. Initially when service start, all calls to backend via client passes. But after like 15-20 mins, all calls starts failing with the ClientAbortion exception. Then there are very less calls (1 in 50 ) with status 200 and rest all are 500.
This service never worked fine.. This is the scenario from the day one.

Below is the code .

Client side error:
ql.transport.exceptions.TransportServerError: 503 Server Error: Service Temporarily Unavailable for url

**Python code**

This is the graph QL client for connecting to backend java server for getting data from database

```
    def __init__(self):
    url = os.getenv('GRAPHQL_URL')
    if url is None:
        logger.error('graphql URL is not defined')
        raise AttributeError('graphql URL is not defined')
    transport = RequestsHTTPTransport(url=url, verify=True, timeout=10)
    self.client = Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True)
```

**Below is the error I am getting in Backend Java Service **

```
ClientAbortException 
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer in realWriteBytes at line 353
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer in flushByteBuffer at line 784
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer in append at line 689
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer in writeBytes at line 388
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer in write at line 366
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream in write at line 96
org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingOutputStream in write at line 287
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator in _flushBuffer at line 2171
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator in writeRaw at line 746
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator in writeRaw at line 659
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator in writeNumber at line 1030
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NumberSerializers$DoubleSerializer in serialize at line 231
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer in serializeFields at line 808
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider in _serialize at line 480
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider in serializeValue at line 400
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch in serialize at line 1514
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter in writeValue at line 1007
org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter in writeInternal at line 456
org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter in write at line 104
org.springframework.web.servlet.function.DefaultEntityResponseBuilder$DefaultEntityResponse in writeEntityWithMessageConverters at line 302
org.springframework.web.servlet.function.DefaultEntityResponseBuilder$DefaultEntityResponse in writeToInternal at line 264
org.springframework.web.servlet.function.AbstractServerResponse in writeTo at line 99
org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.HandlerFunctionAdapter in handle at line 110
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet in doDispatch at line 1071
java.lang.Thread in run at line 833
```

Comment: can you add some more info, what exactly triggers this issue? the full stacktraces? "long time persistent issue" - did it ever worked.. describe in more detail what you did.

Comment: If you're getting a 5xx error this is coming from somewhere outside the GraphQL layer. GraphQL won't return a 5xx.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @gai-jin I  have added the details. Can you please help with this if u know

Comment: @gai-jin as suggested, added  answers to your queries.